# Can Line series be plotted as half solid, half dotted line?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

In an excel sheet contains an chart which is binding the data from another sheet.The chart series are all line series.I need half of the line series as solid line and another half as dotted line.This is can be done manually picking the point changing the line style,this is not the way i needed,the way which i need is from vba code can we do like half line with solid and another with dotted line.

[image]

The above image i need to do this from vba code.I have search my site and applied the solutions provided but those are applying.Any solution provided is much appreciated.

Comment: Probably it's doable via VBA, but there's another automated solution without VBA: split each series into two series - one solid that goes till Dec and one dotted that starts in December. Just use formulas to set the other fields (before or after december) to `""`...

Comment: this is a great question my problem is about Dotted line or dashed line  for future data

Comment: Any reason you sorted the dates alphabetically??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is **no**.

The longer more useful answer is that you must split the series into two parts as this cannot be done for a single series. The line is a single object belonging to the `SeriesCollection` object under it's formatting properties, as demonstrated by the very hacky code, which serves to demonstrate the underlying object model:

```
Sub editChart()

    Dim cO As Chart
    Set cO = ActiveChart
    Dim s As Series

    Set s = cO.SeriesCollection(1)
    s.Format.Line.DashStyle = msoLineDash

    Set s = cO.SeriesCollection(2)
    s.Format.Line.DashStyle = msoLineSolid

End Sub
```

You may be confused with custom formatting for `Points`, of which there may be many attached to a `SeriesCollection`, as these can be individually formatted.

Note that if you want the lines to join up they must share one data point (rather than the first `Series` stopping at point `n` and the second `Series` beginning at point `n+1`).

Comment: The actual short answer is **yes**. You can select a line segment (two single-clicks: one to select the line, another to select the segment) and format that line segment independently of the others. It's easier to have to separate series, though, one formatted with a solid line, one formatted with dashed or dotted lines. See my recent tutorial [Chart with Actual Solid Lines and Projected Dashed Lines](https://peltiertech.com/chart-actual-solid-lines-projected-dashed-lines/).

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlLineStacked
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(14).Format.Line.DashStyle = 3
```

So in my case, the 1st data series is a plain line, but the last point (14 in this graph) has its format changed to dashes.